# Overriding a private method with Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, overriding

Is it possible to override a private method by using Reflection in .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it would need to be `virtual` to be possible to override it (by writing a dynamic type that inherits from the class), and you can't have a `private virtual` (it makes no sense). You could perhaps override an `internal virtual`, but I suspect even this may hit security issues. So ultimately, I'd say no.

Answer (score 5):

Not by using Reflection alone. Perhaps the best you could do is to use Reflection, combined with [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) or the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) to duplicate the class into a new namespace. When you come across the private method you want to replace, you don't copy it, you emit your replacement.

However, there are many techniques a developer can use that make this technique much, much harder. Breaking the implementation of the class into many private or internal classes is one such.

Note: using the CodeDom you'd have to build the graph in memory, compile it, and then load the resulting assembly.

This is probably a LOT more trouble than it is worth.

The other way to do it would be to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble the class, take the code and build your own class from it with the method replace. Again there are significant technical and legal hurdles to overcome. You may learn a lot from the disassembled code though.

Answer (score 1):

Not by using Reflection. You need to use some sort of AOP.

Answer (score 1):

[Typemock Isolator](http://learn.typemock.com/) is supposed to be able to do this, but does so through the .NET profiler APIs (according to Roy Osherove in [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/)).